# CA1305: Verbosity when specifying culture

Tags: c#, .net, localization, code-analysis

[CA1305](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SPECIFYIFORMATPROVIDER%29;k%28VS.ERRORLIST%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true)  is raised when there exists an overload that requires an `IFormatProvider` but this overload isn't used in the code.

For example, the following code raises this warning:

```
string.Format("{0} - {1}", id, name);
```

The obvious way to get rid of this warning is to specify the culture to be used:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} - {1}", id, name);
```

However, I think this is way too verbose.

What alternatives exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the only alternative that would lead to decreased verbosity while still conserving explicit format provider passing would be to use culture-specific façade methods.  Luckily, one typically only formats for InvariantCulture and CurrentCulture, so only two façade methods would be required for each underlying formatting method.

A typical façade method for your sample code might have a signature like this:

```
public static string FormatForInvariantCulture(this string template, params object[] substitutions)
```

and be called as follows:

```
"{0} - {1}".FormatForInvariantCulture(id, name);
```

Another approach for organizing the façade methods would be into culture-specific formatter types that could be injected using IoC techniques.  For example, an interface like the following could be defined for formatting:

```
public interface IFormatter
{
    string Format(string template, params object[] substitutions);
}
```

Culture-specific instances could then be injected into types that need to perform formatting using constructors like the following:

```
public SomeClass(IFormatter systemFormatter, IFormatter uiFormatter)
{
    // ...
}
```

Regardless of the way the façade methods are packaged, it is important to consider that CA2241 ([ProvideCorrectArgumentsToFormattingMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182361.aspx)) will not examine usage of the methods, so it might be worthwhile considering adding a custom rule to do so.

Comment: OK, that's something I came up with myself, it looks like this in my code currently: `Format.Invariant("{0} - {1}", id, name)` and `Format.ForUI`. The problem is that this only solves `string.Format`. It wouldn't solve any other case of this warning...

Comment: Yup.  You would presumably end up creating façade method pairs for each formatting method you call frequently.  Also, if you go this route, you should be aware that CA2241 ([ProvideCorrectArgumentsToFormattingMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182361.aspx)) won't screen the façade, so you might want to consider adding a custom rule that will.

Comment: What do you think about a static class `For` with two properties `Invariant` and `UI`? `Invariant` would simply return `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `UI` would return `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. This would lead to code like this: `string.Format(For.Invariant, "{0} - {1}", id, name);` and additionally this could be used in any scenario that raises CA1305 and would solve the problem with CA2241.

Comment: This just changes the means by which you retrieve the format providers to a type and properties with shorter names.  Personally, I wouldn't go this route since it substitutes well-known references with custom stuff with no benefit other than shorter names.

Comment: There is one other major category of approach that I just recalled while writing that last comment.  I'll add it to my answer, along with the concern for CA2241.

Comment: But the long names are actually the only problem I am having. Am I the only one seeing these long, verbose culture identifiers as a problem that clutters the code?

Comment: Perhaps. <g>  My own pet peeve about CA1305 is that it doesn't recognize when the format provider is irrelevant because I'm only passing string arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Adding formatters via DI is something I would like to avoid as this would in itself add serious clutter to my code. Maybe I need to restructure my code completely. Most occurrences of this warning stem from formatting messages for exceptions and from formatting messages for logging. Maybe I should simply move these formattings to their own classes. This would remove that clutter from my business classes.

Answer (score 0):

If long names are the main problem, creating and reusing an object with a short name like `invC` for invariant culture could be a solution.

```
    CultureInfo invC = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    string.Format(invC, "{0} - {1}", id, name);
```